# foreach creating trouble in echo

Tags: php

```
<?php foreach($products as $product){ 
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($product); // line 1
?>
<tr>// line 2
    <td align="center"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $product['sku']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $product['status']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $product['date_time']; ?></td>
    <td align="center">Edit / Delete</td>               
</tr>
<?php }  exit;?>
```

**line 1 is printing all records but line 2 is printing only one records. why?**

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// if your products array is like this then it will result successfully
$array1 = Array
            (
                '0' => Array
                    (
                        'messageId' => 9,
                        'userId' => 47,
                        'petId' => 68,
                        'message' => 'how hello',
                        'senderId' => 48,
                        'senderPetId' => 66,
                        'messageCreateTime' => '2015-07-31 11:44:59'
                    ),
                '1' => Array
                    (
                        'messageId' => 8,
                        'userId' => 49,
                        'petId' => 69,
                        'message' => 'pppppppppp',
                        'senderId' => 48,
                        'senderPetId' => 67,
                        'messageCreateTime' => '2015-07-31 11:15:16'
                    ),
                '2' => Array
                    (
                        'messageId' => 6,
                        'userId' => 48,
                        'petId' => 67,
                        'message' => 'gggg',
                        'senderId' => 49,
                        'senderPetId' => 69,
                        'messageCreateTime' => '2015-07-31 11:13:42'
                    ),                  
                '3' => Array
                    (
                        'messageId' => 2,
                        'userId' => 48,
                        'petId' => 67,
                        'message' => 'aaaaaaaa',
                        'senderId' => 47,
                        'senderPetId' => 68,
                        'messageCreateTime' => '2015-07-31 11:15:33'
                    )

            );

?>
<table border="1">
<?php foreach($array1 as $product){ 
?>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $product['messageId'] ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $product['userId'] ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $product['senderId'] ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $product['messageCreateTime'] ?></td>
    <td align="center">Edit / Delete</td>               
</tr>
<?php } exit;?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually friends problem was in my variable. `$product` returns two arrays row and rows when I did  `$product->rows` then it printed all.

Answer (score -2):

```
    <?php foreach($products as $product){ 
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($product); // line 1
    ?>
    <tr>// line 2
        <td align="center"><?php echo $product->name ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $product->sku ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $product->status ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $product->date_time ?></td>
        <td align="center">Edit / Delete</td>               
    </tr>
    <?php }  exit;?>
```